# Calculate the double integral $ \iint x e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ using polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Calculate the integral $R \iint f(x,y) \ dx dy$ of $f(x,y)= x e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ using polar coordinates if $R$ is the first quadrant ($x \ge 0, y \ge 0$). I figured out the integral bounds for the 2nd integral ($0 \le\Theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$) but I'm not sure how to find the bounds for the first integral ($r$). Help?

Comment: What do you know about the double integral for polar coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $r$ is simply a positive number w/o upper bound.  The double integral can be separated to two integrals, giving the answer $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: This seems to me to be more of an exercise in polar coordinates than calculus. Here's one way to think about it: you already know that if you want to hit only points in the first quadrant you need your angle to be between $0$ and $\pi/4$. Now you want to hit *every* point in $R$. Clearly the upper bound on the radius is not some finite number (since this will give you a quarter circle!). You will want your radius to vary between $0$ and $\infty$, and these are the bounds you are looking for. Think about why $\{(r,\theta): r\geq 0, \theta\in[0,\pi/4]\}$ is exactly the first quadrant.

Comment: Won't having a radius that varies between **0** and **∞** make it impossible to calculate the integral?

Comment: The first quadrant means $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{pi}{2}$ not $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. Typo here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polar coordinates, $f(r,\theta) = r\cos\theta \cdot e^{-r}$.

\begin{align}
\iint_R f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y &= \iint_R f(r,\theta) \cdot r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} r^2e^{-r}\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \left(\int_0^{+\infty} r^2e^{-r}\,\mathrm{d}r \right) \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta \right)
\end{align}

For the first integral, we can apply integration by parts twice, and note that $r^n e^{-r}|^{+\infty}_0 = 0 \forall n \in \Bbb N^*$. (due to l'Hôpital's Rule)

\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty} r^2e^{-r}\,\mathrm{d}r &= -\int_0^{+\infty} r^2 \,\mathrm{d}(e^{-r}) \\
&= \left. -r^2 e^{-r}\right|^{+\infty}_0 + \int_0^{+\infty} 2r e^{-r} \,\mathrm{d}r \\
&= 0 + 2\int_0^{+\infty} r e^{-r} \,\mathrm{d}r \\
&= 0 - 2\int_0^{+\infty} r \,\mathrm{d}(e^{-r}) \\
&= \left. -r e^{-r}\right|^{+\infty}_0 + 2\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-r} \,\mathrm{d}r \\
&= \left. -2e^{-r} \right|^{+\infty}_0 \\
&= 2
\end{align}

For the second integral, it's equal to $\sin\theta|^{\pi/2}_0  = 1$.

Hence $$\iint_R f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = 2\cdot1 = 2.$$

Comment: Sorry, I've made a careless mistake in the first integral.